# C arry index lookup by log k

Tags: c, recursion

so i need to fine an index (k)in an array when its starting to go down:
{-1,4,6,9,11,15,9,8,4,2}:so i need the index k=6
but the function should run log2k times
any suggestions?
(for now its runing log2n)

```
    int middle_index(int *arr,int first,int last)
{
    int middle,index;
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    if (arr[middle]<arr[middle + 1] && arr[middle]>arr[middle - 1])
    {
        first = middle + 1;
        index = middle_index(arr, first, last);
    }
    else if (arr[middle] > arr[middle + 1] && arr[middle] < arr[middle - 1])
    {
        last = middle - 1;
        index = middle_index(arr, first, last);
    }
    else
    {
        index = middle;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Is it known there is only one location where the array changes from ascending to descending? Is it always strictly ascending or strictly descending (there is no spot where there are two successive elements that are equal?

Comment: yeah there is only 1 locations where its start to descending

Comment: Show the exact text of the problem statement. It is unlikely a teaching exercise of this kind would ask for a result in log k iterations rather than O(log n) iterations. I suppose O(log k) iterations could be feasible by probing at location 1, then 2, then 4, and so on, instead of doing a binary search, but it would still only be O(log k), not log k.

Comment: Your tests look incorrect. Given a point at which to test, you are testing whether the direction changes **exactly** at that point, where `array[middle]` is greater than both the element before it and the element after it. You do not need to do that. You only need to check two elements. That will tell you the direction that elements are going at that point, and that tells you which way to adjust for the next iteration.

Comment: ok,so ill split the array and check in which side i should work,and then checking the every second index in whats after/befor him?

Comment: the full question :Write an efficient function that receives an array of integers and its size n. The array is built using the following method: From the beginning
The array up to a certain place( say k) values in the array are really rising. From the above location k to the end of the array the values decrease
really. The function must return a place (index) of the maximum organ.
(- 1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 15, 9, 8, 4, 2) 
Returns the function:6 
The function must run in the order of log2k

Comment: To find the location in O(log k), test location 1, then 2, then 4, then 8, and so on. When the test shows the elements are descending, do a binary search between the previous tested location and the current tested location. For each test, merely compare two elements to see which way they are going. At the beginning or end of the array, avoid accessing elements outside the array bounds.